# How to solve Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number in windows 10

Tags: python, pyspark

I am having a hard time making PySpark work on my computer. I am using Python 3.7 and Spark 2.4. My code is here below:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(appName="Pyspark mllib Example")
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 108, in _launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
**Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number**
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: did you happen to solve it?

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out it was about the path of Java that was not correct.

I did the following:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

changed the line about `JAVA_HOME` to be:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.12"
```

I also used a virtual env to use the proper version of pyspark, spark and tutti quanti.